# Moodle adding timer in moodle page timer style not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, moodle

I am using `jQuery Countdown Timer & Digital Clock Plugin` into my moodle page as follows:

My code as follows:

```
<?php

require_once('../../config.php');
global $DB;
global $COURSE;
$courseid = $COURSE->id;

if (!$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid))) {
    print_error('invalidcourse', 'block_eparticipation', $courseid);
}

require_login($course);
$PAGE->set_url('/blocks/eparticipation/view.php', array('id' => $courseid));
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
echo $OUTPUT->header();
?>
<html>
    <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Digital-Clock-Plugin-timeTo/timeTo.css">

               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Digital-Clock-Plugin-timeTo/jquery.timeTo.js"></script>  

                <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Digital-Clock-Plugin-timeTo/jquery.timeTo.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#timerdiv').timeTo({
                            seconds: 60,
                            displayHours: false,
                            countdownAlertLimit: 5,
                            callback: function () {

                            }
                    });
                    });
                 </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="timerdiv"></div>
    </body>
<?php echo $OUTPUT->footer(); ?>
</html>
```

But it gets conflicted with the `moodle` page and I am getting a timer which is not showing correctly as follows:
[image]

Please check the timer API here:[API TIMER](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Digital-Clock-Plugin-timeTo.html)

How can I make the necessary changes in API files so that it works correctly on Moodle page.

```
**Note:** If I remove `echo $OUTPUT->header();` and `echo $OUTPUT->footer();` from my page then timer works correctly without crashing style.
```

How can I correct this?

**Moodle version: 2.9.1**

Comment: moodle's header() typically already includes the <head> tag, so you probably have two <head> tags, which is wacky. inject the script into the body instead.

Comment: @dandavis as you said I have removed <head></head> and put the scripts inside <body> still same problem exists.

Comment: can you post the whole rendered view-source of the page? (redact anything sensitive)

Comment: @dandavis you can use the above code as just copy paste as page inside a page inside a block and access it you will get the same!!